# django user to be populated in LDAP

Tags: django, ldap, populate

I would like when a user creates an account in Django, that the user information :
- Username
- Password
- Email
- First and Last Name
- Mobile

Gets also populated in my LDAP server. Also when the user get deactivated, this gets reflected in LDAP.
Authentication will still be done in Django. 
I need the user information as i have another application which is getting the user info from LDAP. I need both to be have the same user universe.
Are there any snippet that does that already ?

I saw many code to authenticate thourgh LDAP, but what i really need is to populate the LDAP directory with my Django user on the fly

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/893/), it should do exactly what you're after (a bit old though, so YMMV with newer django)